# Counting Distinct Values with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with the below data example:

```
IssueNumber    Client
100            Client 1
100            Client 1
101            Client 1
102            Client 2
102            Client 2
```

I want to count the number of unique IssueNumbers for each client.  So the end result would be:

```
Client    Count
Client 1  2
Client 2  1
```

I have a list of the clients in a separate tab from the main data, and am trying to look up using COUNTIFS, and passing the Client name as one of the criteria, but I am struggling to figure out how to count the unique issues.

This must be really simple, but it is Friday afternoon and my brain has given up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few more options:

```
=SUM(IF(((MATCH($A$2:$A$6&$B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6&$B$2:$B$6,0))>=(ROW($A$2:$A$6)-(MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$6))-1)))*($B$2:$B$6=D2)=1,1,0))
```

&

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$6=D2,MATCH($A$2:$A$6&"_"&$B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6&"_"&$B$2:$B$6,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1),1))
```

Both the above formulas are array formula so should be entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Its Friday Morning here so I am not so burnt out yet,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6=D2)*1/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,$A$2:$A$6))
```

[image]

Comment: As first thought, relatively easy...helps to take a break sometimes!

Comment: This wouldn't work if the clients were to share an issue number though I think.  If that cant happen then it's all good

Comment: Also, over large ranges that construction is notoriously slower than the equivalent FREQUENCY/MATCH set-up.