# Excel Count Distinct where other columns match and sum of another column = 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to answer the question of how many parts were successful by counting the distinct Part Labels where PartName matches, and the sum of LabelFailures = 0.

```
PartName | PartLabel | LabelFailure
---------+-----------+-------------
    a    |     1     |    1
    a    |     1     |    0
    a    |     2     |    0
    a    |     2     |    0
    b    |     1     |    0
```

Desired Results:

```
PartName | PartsLabelSucceeded
---------+--------------------
    a    |     1
    b    |     1
```

This question might be similar to these two, but I'm having a hard time holding the individual components in my head to apply the answers to this particular situation. I've been trying to use COUNTIFS, but haven't found a way to fit both criteria in correctly.
[Excel Count Unique Values on Multiple Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199604/excel-count-unique-values-on-multiple-criteria)
[Excel Count Distinct Values with Multiple Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169733/counting-distinct-values-with-multiple-criteria)

Comment: would be easier with a helper column, are you adverse to that?

Comment: I don't mind a helper column. What kind should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper column.

In D2 put:

```
=(COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$B$1:B2,B2)=1)*(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,1)=0)
```

[image]

Then insert a pivot table with PartName as the Rows And Count in the Values.

[image]

OR List the PartName manually and use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,G2)
```

[image]

---

This can also be done with a formula, without the helper if one wants to list the partNames:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$6=F2)*(COUNTIFS(A:A,$A$2:$A$6,B:B,$B$2:$B$6,C:C,1)=0)/(COUNTIFS(A:A,$A$2:$A$6,B:B,$B$2:$B$6)+($A$2:$A$6<>F2)+(COUNTIFS(A:A,$A$2:$A$6,B:B,$B$2:$B$6,C:C,1)>0))))
```

[image]